# Why is my website showing as secure in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: tls, certificates

I am facing an issue with [my clients website](https://www.thebestbetonsports.com/). It is showing as fully secure in Mozila Firfox but not in Google Chrome. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot of TLS info in Google Chrome.]

[image: Screenshot of TLS info in Mozilla Firefox.]

Comment: In Chrome you can see what the issue is by opening the developer tools  (settings > more tools> developer tools) and press on the error/warning icons.

Comment: Also this was quite easy to google..

Comment: @toom I agree it was quite easy to Google - the question is quite poor, you're right.

Comment: Or a free service like SSL Labs, https://www.ssllabs.com

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! As suggested by @toom if you use Developer Mode you can see what the issue is. Looks like it's a Symantec certificate you're using which is causing the issue, please see blockquote below.

> The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://www.paypalobjects.com will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.

I will assume you're not aware but Google are dropping support on Symantec certificates that were generated on the old PKI infrastructure.

[Google drops Symantec certificate support](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/google-outlines-ssl-apocalypse-for-symantec-certificates/)

To further add to this as per Daves comments please see [Symantec sells SSL business to DigiCert](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/business/symantec-sells-ssl-business-to-digicert-for-950m-in-cash-and-30-percent-shares/)

Comment: To further add to this I got the warning using the method suggested by Toom, you will see the exact same message if you follow those instructions. (You will also see the link to your site within the message I just didn't copy & paste that bit as it's a given it's going to be for your site)

Comment: The article you link is obsolete. Instead of rebuilding as first proposed (I assume you meant 'brought out' not 'bought out'), Symantec instead sold the whole CA business to DigiCert. See [the same source a week later](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/business/symantec-sells-ssl-business-to-digicert-for-950m-in-cash-and-30-percent-shares/)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you. Yes, that was a typo, my mistake. I will correct it now. However; this does not change my answer to the OPs question, Google still is not supporting those certificates and he will need to get a new certificate so that Google will consider it secure.  I will edit to add your link.

Comment: I have also removed section on rebuilding as they first proposed.

Comment: In Developer Tools  you may need to select the **Security tab**. Look for red triangles, e.g. `Certificate - missing. This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_SYMANTEC_LEGACY).`More on the [Symantec certificate apocalypse](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/google-outlines-ssl-apocalypse-for-symantec-certificates/).